# How to route Dynamic url in Core php

Tags: php, routes

1. index.php
2. cms-page.php

if Request ULR  is  
**www.example.com/service** or  
**www.example.com/about-us** 
than **cms-page.php** should be open 
how do i route . what to write and where to write to get such result . Thanks .

Comment: in Codeigniter Syntax is following (config.php):  
 $route['(:any)'] = "ControllerClass/ControllerMethod/$1";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In core php, you can do something like this to achieve.

```
//get request url
$url = rawurldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

//match the request url with above urls. 
if(preg_match('/service/', $url) || preg_match('/about-us/', $url)){ 
//open cms page. 
include('cms-page.php');
}
```

In general Practice, Keep your url decoding and redirecting part in a seperate php file and then redirect them to router which should take approriate action. 
Please see the below structure.

```
URL DECODER -> ROUTER (takes to controller) -> CONTROLLER (determines view ) -> VIEW
```