# Redirect to a specific folder -PHP

Tags: php

So I created a register/login system. Once they register, a folder will be created automatically with their username as the folder name(like a personal folder). I want them to be redirected to that folder once they logged in.

Can I use:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/Parentfolder/theusersfolder);
```

then replace *theuserfolder* to redirect the user to his folder? or something that might help?

Comment: If the folder is only created when they register, what are you going to put in that folder so that when you redirect them to it, something happens other than just a 401 error? Or are you using `.htaccess` to rewrite the URL to a different page?

Comment: the user folder is where they can put their files or create another folder. I just want to prevent the user to access the Parent folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating Folder. You can use dynamic Routing. It will also help you when user renames their username.

If you are using Core PHP these links will help you

- [How to route Dynamic url in Core php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549853/how-to-route-dynamic-url-in-core-php)
- https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-build-a-basic-server-side-routing-system-in-php-e52e613cf241

Or you can use any PHP framework